# How to assert two lists are not equivalent if in different order using Fluent Assertions

Tags: c#, tdd, fluent-assertions

Using [Fluent Assertions](https://github.com/dennisdoomen/fluentassertions/wiki) we can assert that two collections are equal (in terms of property values) using something like:

```
list1.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(list2);
```

Assuming `list1` and `list2` are contain the same objects `in any order`, the assertion will be true.

If we want to assert the lists are in the exact order we can do something like this:

```
list1.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(list2, o => o.WithStrictOrdering());
```

I'm looking for something that assert false if the list contian the same objets in the `wrong order` but I can't find any.

What is the best way using Fluent Assertions?

PS - it a  kind of academic curiosity, It might not even be that useful in reality :)

Comment: What do you want to happen if `x` has [5, 6, 8] and `y` has `[5, 6, 7, 8]`? Should it be considered equivalent?

Comment: no, I want to assert if it IS NOT the exact objects in the the exact order.  I'm not even sure this will be useful, I just wanted to know if it is possible. so that would be false as 7 doesn't exist in the first list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: Now that I understand what davy is asking for (see comment below) I updated my code to this solution. Although the syntax is similar, it is not a FluentAssertion extension, but with some manipulation it could be.

```
public static class IEnumerableAssertionExtensions
{
    public static void ShouldContainInWrongOrder<TSubject>(this IEnumerable<TSubject> source, IEnumerable<TSubject> expected)
    {
        var remaining = expected.ToList();
        var inOrder = true;
        foreach (var subject in source)
        {
            if (inOrder && !ReferenceEquals(subject, remaining[0]))
            {
                inOrder = false;
            }
            var s = subject;
            Execute.Verification.ForCondition(() => remaining.Remove(s)).FailWith("Expected item in the collection: {0}", subject.ToString());
        }

        Execute.Verification.ForCondition(() => remaining.Count == 0).FailWith(string.Format("{0} more item{1} than expected found in the list.", remaining.Count, ((remaining.Count == 1) ? string.Empty : "s")));
        Execute.Verification.ForCondition(() => !inOrder).FailWith("list items are ordered identically");
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class TestFoo
{
    class Thing
    {
        public int i;
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void MyMethod()
    {
        var a1 = new Thing { i=0 };
        var a2 = new Thing { i=1 };
        var a3 = new Thing { i=2 };
        var a4 = new Thing { i=2 };
        var list1 = new List<Thing> { a1, a2, a3 };
        var list2 = new List<Thing> { a1, a2, a3 };
        var list3 = new List<Thing> { a3, a2, a1 };
        var list4 = new List<Thing> { a1, a2, a3, a4 };
        var list5 = new List<Thing> { a3, a2 };

        list1.ShouldContainInWrongOrder(list3); // Succeeds
        list1.ShouldContainInWrongOrder(list2); // Fails
        list1.ShouldContainInWrongOrder(list4); // Fails
        list1.ShouldContainInWrongOrder(list5); // Fails
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks but I'm looking for something like a Should().NotContainInOrder() so that I can write a test that passes when both list contain the  same objects but in a different order.

Comment: Oh! I see what you are asking for now. I know of no direct FA solution, but see my edit in the above answer.